# Automatic selection of window to share in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, screensharing, recordrtc

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

This example works just fine, but the question is: can i avoid display of that ugly window that asks to pick a window to share (or a full screen), instead getting a list of windows and picking it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes !

```
chromium --auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen --url <url to start the stream>
```